ASP.Net webapp stuck in Azure AD B2C authentication loop in only one environment
We have a web app that we're trying to change over to Azure B2C for authentication.
It works fine in our test environments (connecting to test B2C tenants) and also locally.
Before we tried to roll it out to our live environment we first tested the live B2C tenant against a test web app and that worked fine.
When it went live, we could successfully log in using localhost from VS connecting to the live B2C tenant and from the test environment to the live B2C tenant, but from the live webapp to live B2C tenant got stuck in a loop:

webapp redirects to Azure for login
Azure authenticates successfully and returns to webapp
webapp redirects to Azure for login again
Ad infinitum

The reply URL is correct in live, the reply URL is listed in the Azure B2C app registration and it's hitting it ok, but our webapp is not recognising the success.
The only different I've been able to spot so far is that the call to our webapp (after authresp returns successfully) has an additional 'Set-cookie' header in the test environment and from VS on localhost, which is missing in live. It's to set a '.aspnet.cookies' cookie, which I believe holds the ASP.Net session state.
We've no idea why (or where) that set-cookie is going missing. We've turned off Cloudflare and our load balancer, and the set-cookie is still missing. Any ideas what could cause this or how it's sent to Azure AD B2C so I can check to see where/when it's going missing?
All three (test/localhost/live) are running the same version of the webapp and connecting to the same Azure AD B2C tenant. Azure AD B2C is authenticating successfully in all three cases.

Can you please share the code repo?

I can’t sadly - it’s a large proprietary website.

Are you following any doc?
